# Squares and Rationalization

Tags: contest-math

I was solving this question, and I'm hitting a wall.

> If ${1\over{\sqrt{2011+\sqrt{2011^2-1}}}}=\sqrt{m}-\sqrt{n}$, where $m$ and $n$ are positive integers, what is the value of $m+n$?

I tried to solve this question with two approaches:

> > ${\sqrt{m}-\sqrt{n}}={1\over{\sqrt{2011+\sqrt{2011^2-1}}}}$
> >     $={\sqrt{2011+\sqrt{2011^2-1}}\over{2011+\sqrt{2011^2-1}}}$
> >     $={({\sqrt{2011+\sqrt{2011^2-1}})(\sqrt{2011^2-1}-2011)}\over{2011^2-2012}}$
> >
> > Squaring,
> >
> > $m+n-2\sqrt{mn}$
> >     $={{{{(2011+\sqrt{2011^2-1}})\{4022(2011-\sqrt{2011^2-1})-1\}}}\over{2011^4+2012^2-2\cdot{2011^2}\cdot{2012}}}$
> >
> > This goes nowhere

And

> > ${\sqrt{m}-\sqrt{n}}={1\over{\sqrt{2011+\sqrt{2011^2-1}}}}$
> >
> > Squaring
> >
> > ${m+n-2\sqrt{mn}}$
> >     $={{\sqrt{2011^2-1}-2011}\over{(2011)(2010)-1}}$
> >
> > Which again, probably goes nowhere.

Can anyone help?

Comment: i would multiply by $$\sqrt{2011-\sqrt{2011^2-1}}$$

Comment: Let m = n+1 and solve for n.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

after my hint we have $$\sqrt{2011-\sqrt{2011^2-1}}=\sqrt{m}-\sqrt{n}$$
after squaring we get
$$2011-2\sqrt{1011030}=m+n-s\sqrt{mn}$$
we set
$$m+n=2011$$
$$nm=1011030$$
solving this System we get
$$m_1=1005$$
$$m_2=1006$$
can you finish?

Comment: Notice you don't even need to solve the system now that the question asks for the value of $m+n$.

Answer (score 4):

Hint

$\dfrac1{\sqrt{2011+\sqrt{2011^2-1}}}$
$=\dfrac1{\sqrt{2011+2\sqrt{1005*1006}}}$
$=\dfrac1{\sqrt{\sqrt{1005}+\sqrt{1006}}^2}$

Comment: Just... Wow. Incredible.

Answer (score 1):

HINT:
$$(a+\sqrt{a^2-1})(a-\sqrt{a^2-1})=a^2-(a^2-1)=?$$

$$\implies\sqrt{a+\sqrt{a^2-1}}\cdot\sqrt{a-\sqrt{a^2-1}}=?$$